# How can I animate a view from alpha value 1 to 0, hide the view, animate the view from 0 to 1, then unhide the view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, hide, animatewithduration

I have an alarm screen with controls for brightness and other things. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish with it:

I have a black `scrim` covering all the elements on the screen that I am animating from alpha 1 to 0 after 5 seconds of no user interaction. When the scrim is tapped it should animate from alpha 0 to 1 and hide so I can interact with the controls beneath it. Then once again after 5 seconds of inactivity, the scrim should animate from 0 to 1 again. The scrim should hide and unhide whenever the user taps it.

Right now I'm getting the animations to all work properly using `animateWithDuration` but at the completion of each animation to alpha 0 the scrim does not hide so I am unable to access the controls underneath. How can I accomplish these animations in a way that doesn't obstruct the controls on the screen whenever the alpha of `scrim` is 0?

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideScrim)];

    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    [self.scrim addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self showScrim];
}

-(void)showScrim {

    self.scrim.alpha = 0.0;
    self.scrim.hidden = NO;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50 delay:5.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.scrim.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}

-(void)hideScrim
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50 animations:^{
        self.scrim.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.scrim.hidden = YES;
        [self showScrim];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling  `[self showScrim];` in the completion of your hideScrim animation? that is your issue your  `showScrim` put your view again visible calling  `self.scrim.hidden = NO;`

Comment: @ReinierMelian my reasoning for including `[self showScrim];` in the completion of my hideScrim animation was to show 'scrim' after 5 seconds of inactivity following a tap from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your hide method to

```
-(void)hideScrim
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50 animations:^{
        self.scrim.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.scrim.hidden = YES;
        [self performSelector:@selector(showScrim) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];//if you want to show again after 5 seconds
    }];
}
```

and show method to

```
-(void)showScrim {

    self.scrim.alpha = 0.0;
    self.scrim.hidden = NO;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.scrim.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

if you need delay in show initially, try the below code

```
self.scrim.hidden = YES;
[self performSelector:@selector(showScrim) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
```

Comment: This answer works the best so far! There is one problem though. When I first visit this screen the `scrim` immediately begins to animate to alpha 1. I want this initial animation to have a 5-second delay. I can achieve this by changing the `showScrim` delay to 5.0, but then I am unable to use the controls for the first 5 seconds as the scrim is not initially hidden.

Comment: you can use the code in completion block of hideScrim method initially. ie. hide the scrim first and call show method with delay using perform selector.

Comment: Thank you!! That worked perfectly. This was my first attempt at animation and I've been at it all day.